# Cannot use some Android emulators: Permission Denied

Tags: android, maven, android-emulator, adt

I have problems running the latest Android emulators like "Nexus 7, Android 4.1.2". The emulator can start, but I can't deploy on it (by Maven) which probably depends on this problem: When I switch on the phone to the Apps view, I get **"Unfortunately, launcher has stopped"** and LogCat gives me the following output:

> 01-02 14:30:26.313: W/ActivityManager(151): Permission denied:
>   checkComponentPermission() owningUid=1000 01-02 14:30:26.313:
>   W/BroadcastQueue(151): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent {
>   act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE_OPTIONS flg=0x10
>   cmp=com.android.settings/.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider (has
>   extras) } from android (pid=970, uid=10014) is not exported from uid
>   1000 due to receiver
>   com.android.settings/com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider

My AndroidManifest looks like this:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="5"
    android:targetSdkVersion="7" />

<application
    android:name="my.domain.appcontext.ApplicationContext"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" 
    android:allowBackup="true">
    <activity
        android:name="my.domain.appcontext.activities.MainActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="my.domain.appcontext.activities.MainMenuDialogActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="my.domain.appcontext.activities.DistrictMenuDialogActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="my.domain.appcontext.activities.StreetMenuPreselectionDialogActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="my.domain.appcontext.activities.StreetMenuDialogActivity"
        android:excludeFromRecents="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Dialog" >
    </activity>

    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps"
                  android:required="true" />
</application>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to send the `android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE` broadcast somewhere in your code? This is an **Android OS broadcast**, so you won't have permission to use it if you are...

Comment: No, I don't send any broadcasts. That's why I posted the AndroidManifest to show that there are no BroadcastReceivers set.